# React: Cant retrieve data from server on client side

Tags: reactjs, post, crud

This is my first time trying to do a CRUD app using react. I am trying to display a list of all of the users from a table (from the server) using a get request.

For some reason I cant get the data from server to the client.
This is the code for the server

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();
const mysql = require('mysql');

const db = mysql.createConnection({
    user: 'root',
    host: 'localhost',
    password: 'password',
    database: 'table1'
});

db.connect((err) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log('Connected to database');
    }
});

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

app.post("/create", (req, res) => {
    const name = req.body.name;
    const age = req.body.age;
    const country = req.body.country;
    const position = req.body.position;
    const wage = req.body.wage;
  
    db.query(
      "INSERT INTO users (name, age, country, position, wage) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)",
      [name, age, country, position, wage],
      (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
        } else {
          res.send("Values Inserted");
        }
      }
    );
  });

app.get("/users", (req, res) => {
    db.query("SELECT * FROM users", (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            res.send(result);
            console.log(result);
            console.log('success sending data');  //this prints and executes successfully
        }
    });
});

app.listen(3001, () => {
  console.log('Server is running on port 3001');
});
```

And this is the code I have for the client, the value received is undefined,

```
import Axios from 'axios';
import './App.css';
import {useState} from 'react';

function App() {
  const[name, setName] = useState("");
  const[age, setAge] = useState(0);
  const[country, setCountry] = useState("");
  const[position, setPosition] = useState("");
  const[wage, setWage] = useState(0);

  const [usersList, setUsersList] = useState([]);

  const getUsers = () => {
    Axios.get('http://localhost:3001/users').then((response) => {
      console.log(response.data);
      setUsersList(response.data);
    });
  };

  const addUser = () => {
    console.log(name, age, country, position, wage);
    Axios.post('http://localhost:3001/create', {name: name, age: age, country: country, position: position, wage: wage})

    .then(()=> console.log('success'));
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="information">
        <label>Name</label>
        <input type="text" onChange={(event) => {setName(event.target.value)}}/>
        <label>Age</label>
        <input type="number" onChange={(event)=> { setAge(event.target.value)}}/>
        <label>Country</label>
        <input type="text" onChange={(event)=> {setCountry(event.target.value)}}/>
        <label>Position</label>
        <input type="text" onChange={(event)=> {setPosition(event.target.value)}}/>
        <label>Wage</label>
        <input type="number" onChange={(event)=> {setWage(event.target.value)}}/>

        <button onClick={addUser}> Add Employee</button>
     
      </div>

      --
      <div className="users">
        <button onClick={getUsers}>Show Users</button>
        {usersList.map((val, key) => {
          console.log(val.name);
          return <div >
            <h3> Name: {val.name}</h3>
           
          </div>
        })}
      </div>

    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I have tried to debug by using console.log statements and still can't figure out what is wrong

Comment: have you added the address of your server as proxy to react package.json

Comment: If you don't tell us the error or message you receive, we won't be able to help you

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the "useEffect" hook to fetch data. The useEffect hook will run once your component is rendered.

```
import {useState, useEffect} from 'react'

/* Inside your component. */
useEffect(async () = {
 const response = await Axios.get('http://localhost:3001/users');
 setUsersList([...response.data]);
}, []);
```

Passing an empty array as the second argument to the useEffect hook means that the function will run only once, when your component is rendered.

If you want to you could also add an additional state variable:

```
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
```

And you can set loading to false once your data is fetched:

```
useEffect(async () = {
 const response = await Axios.get('http://localhost:3001/users');
 setLoading(false);
 setUsersList([...response.data]);
}, []);
```

By using this approach you can render your component only once the loading variable is set to false (data is fetched), and otherwise render a simple "Loading..." text on the screen:

```
function renderUsers(){
    if(loading) return (<p>Loading...</p>);
    
    return usersList.map((val, key) => {
      console.log(val.name);
      return <div >
        <h3> Name: {val.name}</h3>
       
      </div>
    });
}
```

If this does not work it's probably something wrong with your back-end. Navigate to localhost:3001/users in your browser to see if you actually get a response.